# how to add or customise tab in learnpress plugin

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

I am stuck in customisation and/or adding a new tab in Learnpress wordpress plugins. here is my course page, I have already added a new tab named "Entry Requirements" but I want to include a text field in the dashboard for each new custom tab. :
https://eoeisc.gipcl.org.uk/courses/your-complete-guide-to-photography/

I would be really grateful if anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your question adding tabs in wp-admin course backend or frontend ?

Comment: @DpEN

In the Learnpress plugins, it has fixed tabs and for each tabs there is field to insert data in the wp-admin backend. For example, they have Overview, Curriculum, Review, Teachers etc.  In order to active or de-active those tabs, there is an option in the Appearance>Customise. I have managed to add 2 tabs name "Entry Requirements" and "Progression Degrees" in the customisation section but I cannot add text field in the wp-admin backend where I will insert data and it will appear on the single course page next to Course Overview and Curriculum tabs.